# How to get only value from var using debug in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Am currently getting the device count from using debug var stmt. I am trying to get only the value but output does comes along with variable.

```
- name: get number of device on each rack blades
      #set_fact:
        #devices_count: "{{ result.ansible_facts.blades.{{item}}.device|length }}"

      debug: var=result.ansible_facts.blades.{{item}}.device|length
      register: devices_count
      with_sequence:
        - start=0 end="{{ blades_count|int - 1 }}"
```

Output currently getting from the above code :

```
    TASK [get number of device on each rack blades] *************************************************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => {
        "item": "0",
        "result.ansible_facts.blades.0.device|length": "10"
    }
    ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => {
        "item": "1",
        "result.ansible_facts.blades.1.device|length": "8"
    }
    ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => {
        "item": "2",
        "result.ansible_facts.blades.2.device|length": "4"
    }
```

How can I get only value part IE, 10, 8, 4.

Ss there a way we can filter or get .value part or use some regex ?

Any help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` option of the [`debug` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) is expecting a string which is the name of a variable.

You are feeding in that option a jinja2 expression (I'm even surprised you get a result at all) that should be passed to a `msg` option with jinja2 expression markers (double curly braces). The `item` expansion will need to be modified to work.

Moreover, registering the result of a debug task has no interest (debug the registered var in a next task to see for yourself).

Last, I strongly recommend you adopt the modern full yaml syntax for all your tasks rather than using/mixing with the `key=value` old shortcut syntax for modules.

The following should get you to the expected result

```
- name: debug my values
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.ansible_facts.blades[item].device | length }}"
  with_sequence: start=0 end="{{ blades_count | int - 1 }}"
```

You can even adopt the new [`loop` syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) and its [`with_sequence` replacement](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence)

```
- name: debug my values
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.ansible_facts.blades[item].device | length }}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, blades_count | int) | list }}"
```

Edit: Following your comment, I'm not really sure of what you wish to store and loop over. Example below is to store the raw values in a simple list (not tested without a sample data provided). If this is not what you expect, please ask a new question for this specific problem and provide more details about your actual data structure and the expected result.

```
- name: Create a list with device number length
  vars:
    current_number: "{{ result.ansible_facts.blades[item].device | length }}"
  set_fact:
    device_numbers: "{{ device_numbers | default([]) + [current_number] }}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, blades_count | int) | list }}"

- name: Show device_numbers list
  debug:
    var: device_numbers
```

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator. how can i store this "msg" value so, as i need to use that in nested loop.

Comment: Edited (although questions are not supposed to contain several questions). As explained ask a new one with details if this is not what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator. creating a list worked (atleast what i wanted to get/try) but now nested loop not working as expected. As you suggested, I have created new question with full details. if you can have a look that will be great help. thanks Again
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780422/how-to-run-nested-for-loop-on-list-in-ansible

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *" ... getting the device count ... how can I get only value part ie, 10, 8, 4?"*

A: Given the dictionary below for testing the number of devices in each blade (3, 4, 5)

```
blades:
  1: [devA, devB, devC]
  2: [devA, devB, devC, devD]
  3: [devA, devB, devC, devD, devE]
```

the tasks

```
- set_fact:
    devices: "{{ blades|dict2items|
                 json_query('[].value')|
                 map('length')|
                 list }}"
- debug:
    var: devices
```

give

```
"devices": [
    3, 
    4, 
    5
]
```

---

Details

[*dict2items*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) converts the dictionary to a list

```
[
    {
        "key": 1, 
        "value": [
            "devA", 
            "devB", 
            "devC"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "key": 2, 
        "value": [
            "devA", 
            "devB", 
            "devC", 
            "devD"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "key": 3, 
        "value": [
            "devA", 
            "devB", 
            "devC", 
            "devD", 
            "devE"
        ]
    }
]
```

[*json_query*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) selects the list of values

```
[
    [
        "devA", 
        "devB", 
        "devC"
    ], 
    [
        "devA", 
        "devB", 
        "devC", 
        "devD"
    ], 
    [
        "devA", 
        "devB", 
        "devC", 
        "devD", 
        "devE"
    ]
]
```

and [*map*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#map) applies the filter *length* to each element of the list

```
[
    3, 
    4, 
    5
]
```