# how to run nested for loop on list in ansible

Tags: ansible

Am trying to get the status of each devices present on each enclosures. for that :

1. first get the enclosure Count
2. now, get the device count on each enclosure's deviceBays
3. now, run nested loop to get status of device ie,
   for each enclosure in enclosureCount
           for each device in deviceCount
                get the device status

below code, i tried to do this, by getting enclosurelist, devicelist and used nested loop

```
tasks:
   - name: get the enclosure details
     enclosure_facts:
       config: "{{ config }}"
     delegate_to: localhost
     register: result

   - name: set the enclosure count
     set_fact:
       enclosure_count: "{{ result.ansible_facts.enclosures|length }}"
   - debug: var=enclosure_count

   - name: generate a list for number of enclosure_count value
     set_fact:
       enclosurelist: "{{ enclosurelist | default([]) + [item | int]  }}"
     with_sequence: start=0 end="{{enclosure_count|int - 1}}"
   - name: display the enclosurelist values
     debug: var=enclosurelist

   - name: Create a list with device number length
     vars:
       current_number: "{{ result.ansible_facts.enclosures[item].deviceBays | length }}"
     set_fact:
       device_numbers: "{{ device_numbers | default([]) + [current_number] }}"
     loop: "{{ range(0, enclosure_count | int) | list }}"

   - name: Show device_numbers list
     debug:
       var: device_numbers

   - name: with_nested loop to display status fo each deviceBays on each enclosures
     debug: var=result.ansible_facts.enclosures.{{item[0]}}.deviceBays.{{item[1]}}.devicePresence
     #with_list:
     #with_indexed_items:
     with_nested:
       - "{{ enclosurelist }}"
       #- "{{ device_numbers|int -1 }}"
       - "{{ device_numbers}}"
```

current output for nested loop is not going through each deviceCount instead static/single vlaue ie, 10

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=[0, u'10']) => {
    "item": [
        0,
        "10"
    ],
    "result.ansible_facts.enclosures.0.deviceBays.10.devicePresence": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: list object has no element 10"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[0, u'10']) => {
    "item": [
        0,
        "10"
    ],
    "result.ansible_facts.enclosures.0.deviceBays.10.devicePresence": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: list object has no element 10"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[0, u'10']) => {
    "item": [
        0,
        "10"
    ],
    "result.ansible_facts.enclosures.0.deviceBays.10.devicePresence": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: list object has no element 10"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1, u'10']) => {
    "item": [
        1,
        "10"
    ],
    "result.ansible_facts.enclosures.1.deviceBays.10.devicePresence": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: list object has no element 10"
}
```

error with "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: list object has no element 10" is to do with actual value starts from 0-9

enclosure_facts result:

```
{
  "ansible_facts": {
    "enclosures": [
      {
        "deviceBayCount": 12,
        "deviceBays": [
          {
            "bayNumber": 1,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 2,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 3,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 4,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 5,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 6,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 7,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
             "bayNumber": 8,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 9,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 10,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {

            "bayNumber": 11,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 12,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "deviceBayCount": 12,
        "deviceBays": [
          {
            "bayNumber": 1,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 2,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 3,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 4,
            "devicePresence": "Present"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 5,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 6,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 7,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
             "bayNumber": 8,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 9,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 10,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {

            "bayNumber": 11,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          },
          {
            "bayNumber": 12,
            "devicePresence": "Absent"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "changed": false,
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
      "config": "",
      "password": null,
      "username": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In ansilble's case, it is usually a full playbook, usually targeted to localhost, with a vars section containing your example data, and the minimal tasks to play to reproduce the problem. I should be able to copy/paste it, save it, play it and get the same result as you. To be precise, in your case, create a var containing an extract of your `enclosure_facts` returned data that we can play with.

Comment: @Zeitounator, I have enclsoure facts results which is around 700 lines, not sure how to attached the file in here. how can pass that info ?

Comment: just get 3/4 objects for your tests.... or cleanup data that is not relevent.

Comment: @Zeitounator, as suggested, edited inital post and added the enclosure_facts result (only required part). you can use that as test data now i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling you are calculating a lot of things just to further loop on them when ansible can do the job for you. I also understood you want to access/display an index for each enclosure (index not in your current data).

I reduced your data sample a bit in the following example but I think it pretty much does all you need. Just adapt so that you make more tasks with loops to display/run modules with the relevant data

Note: when I asked in my comment for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this is exactly what I was thinking about: a playbook you can copy and run directly without having to put all the pieces together. Please think about it for your future questions and answers.

```
---
- name: Manipulate result list demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Data structure reduced and minimfied on single line
    result: {ansible_facts: {enclosures: [{deviceBayCount: 2, deviceBays: [{bayNumber: 1, devicePresence: Present}, {bayNumber: 2, devicePresence: Present}]}, {deviceBayCount: 4, deviceBays: [{bayNumber: 1, devicePresence: Present}, {bayNumber: 2, devicePresence: Present}, {bayNumber: 3, devicePresence: Absent}, {bayNumber: 4, devicePresence: Absent}]}]}, changed: false, invocation: {module_args: {config: , password: null, username: null}}}

  tasks:

    - name: Show initial data (use -v to show)
      debug:
        var: result
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Create a single structure containing all the data we need
      vars:
        my_current_enclosure:
          enclosure_number: "{{ index }}"
          number_of_devices: "{{ item.deviceBays | length }}"
          ## Note this later one can probably be replaced by following ?
          # number_of_devices: "{{ item.deviceBayCount }}"
          deviceBays: "{{ item.deviceBays }}" #  simply copy existing data
      set_fact:
        my_enclosures: "{{ my_enclosures | default([]) + [my_current_enclosure] }}"
      loop: "{{ result.ansible_facts.enclosures | flatten(levels=1) }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: index

    - name: Show the new calculated data structure (use -v to show)
      debug:
        var: my_enclosures
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Display device number for each enclosure
      debug:
        msg: "Enclosure number {{ item.enclosure_number }} has {{ item.number_of_devices }} device(s)"
      loop: "{{ my_enclosures }}"

    - name: Show status of each device bay
      debug:
        msg: "Enclosure: {{ item.0.enclosure_number }} - Bay number: {{ item.1.bayNumber }} - Status: {{ item.1.devicePresence }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('subelements', my_enclosures, 'deviceBays') }}"
```

And the result (run verbosely with `-v` to get more details)

```sh
PLAY [Manipulate result list demo] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show initial data (use -v to show)] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Create a single structure containing all the data we need] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'deviceBayCount': 2, 'deviceBays': [{'bayNumber': 1, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}, {'bayNumber': 2, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}]})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'deviceBayCount': 4, 'deviceBays': [{'bayNumber': 1, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}, {'bayNumber': 2, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}, {'bayNumber': 3, 'devicePresence': 'Absent'}, {'bayNumber': 4, 'devicePresence': 'Absent'}]})

TASK [Show the new calculated data structure (use -v to show)] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Display device number for each enclosure] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'enclosure_number': 0, 'number_of_devices': '2', 'deviceBays': [{'bayNumber': 1, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}, {'bayNumber': 2, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}]}) => {
    "msg": "Enclosure number 0 has 2 device(s)"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'enclosure_number': 1, 'number_of_devices': '4', 'deviceBays': [{'bayNumber': 1, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}, {'bayNumber': 2, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}, {'bayNumber': 3, 'devicePresence': 'Absent'}, {'bayNumber': 4, 'devicePresence': 'Absent'}]}) => {
    "msg": "Enclosure number 1 has 4 device(s)"
}

TASK [Show status of each device bay] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'enclosure_number': 0, 'number_of_devices': '2'}, {'bayNumber': 1, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}]) => {
    "msg": "Enclosure: 0 - Bay number: 1 - Status: Present"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'enclosure_number': 0, 'number_of_devices': '2'}, {'bayNumber': 2, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}]) => {
    "msg": "Enclosure: 0 - Bay number: 2 - Status: Present"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'enclosure_number': 1, 'number_of_devices': '4'}, {'bayNumber': 1, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}]) => {
    "msg": "Enclosure: 1 - Bay number: 1 - Status: Present"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'enclosure_number': 1, 'number_of_devices': '4'}, {'bayNumber': 2, 'devicePresence': 'Present'}]) => {
    "msg": "Enclosure: 1 - Bay number: 2 - Status: Present"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'enclosure_number': 1, 'number_of_devices': '4'}, {'bayNumber': 3, 'devicePresence': 'Absent'}]) => {
    "msg": "Enclosure: 1 - Bay number: 3 - Status: Absent"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'enclosure_number': 1, 'number_of_devices': '4'}, {'bayNumber': 4, 'devicePresence': 'Absent'}]) => {
    "msg": "Enclosure: 1 - Bay number: 4 - Status: Absent"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thanks, didn't know about index logic which you have showed. learned new thing from you. many thanks.

Comment: The `index_var` in `loop_control` used with `loop` is the new way replacing `with_indexed_item` => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-indexed-items